# How to find the possible path(traversing)

Tags: javascript, html, graph-theory

How to find the possible path traversing from below object.

```
var pathObject = {
                A :["B"],
                B :["C", "D"],
                D :["E"],
                C :["F", "E"],
                E :["G"],
                F :["G"],
                G :["H"],
                H :[]                
            }
```

The expected output is:

```
[
   ["A", "B", "C", "F", "G", "H"],
   ["A", "B", "D", "E", "G", "H"],
   ["A", "B", "C", "E", "G", "H"]
];
```

how to achieve this.. I have tried using while loop but i can't able to find the exact logic.

Comment: Please post the code/logic you have tried and highlight what you believe is wrong.

Comment: @JasonCust i have just tried but didn't started... while starting this to solve this puzzle i have confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive is useful for this.

```
var pathObject = {
                A :["B"],
                B :["C", "D"],
                D :["E"],
                C :["F", "E"],
                E :["G"],
                F :["G"],
                G :["H"],
                H :[]                
            }

var paths = []
function findPath(data, currentPath, currentPoint) {
    currentPath.push(currentPoint);
    if(data[currentPoint].length == 0) {
        paths.push(currentPath)
    } else {
        data[currentPoint].map(nextPoint => {
            findPath(data, currentPath.slice(0), nextPoint)
        })
    }
}
findPath(pathObject, [], "A");
console.log(paths)
```